# How the camera hold the wake-lock in Android 4.2?

Tags: android, android-camera, wakelock, android-wake-lock

Normally , we use the wake-lock mechanism to keep the app bright . But when I study the Android Camera , I found there isn't any information about the wake-lock, including acquire the wake-lock and release the wake-lock.

When I set the sleep setting which in the display setting to 15 seconds , that is to say, after 15 seconds the screen will go to sleep if there isn't any operations. But when I launch the Camera and do nothing , I found the screen is bright after the 15 seconds had passed.

So how the camera hold the wake-lock? How the camera keep the screen bright longer than the sleep setting in display setting in Android 4.2? I am confused about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The foreground activity can keep the screen on, while that activity remains in the foreground. The easiest way to do this is to use `android:keepScreenOn="true"` or `setKeepScreenOn(true)` on any widget or container in your activity's layout.

Comment: I search for the code what you said in the Camera and Gallery, but there isn't the result. So I think it doesn't use the way to keep the screen bright.

Comment: @Jerikc: There is also `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` that can be applied to the `Window` as part of activity setup -- in the end, that's what `setKeepScreenOn()` and such use.

Comment: if I set the FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON flag, it means I hold the wake-lock . Right ?

Comment: @Jerikc: Yes, but only while the activity is in the foreground.